# Return how many unique digitis a number contains

Tags: c#, loops, numbers

I have a string of digits and I want to count how many unique digits the string contains.

Example:

```
111222
1002345
000000
```

Expected output:

```
111222 2
1002345 6
000000 1
```

I have achieved this using the following code:

```cs
private static int Counter(string ID)
{
    char[] numbers = new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    List<int> listofmatched = new List<int>();
    var split = ID.ToArray();
    foreach (var num in split)
    {
        if (numbers.Contains(num))
        {
            if (listofmatched.Contains(num))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                listofmatched.Add(num);
            }
        }
    }
    return listofmatched.Count;
}
```

Is there any way to improve the code above? I feel like there's unnecessary loops.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is *digits*. And you want to count how many *digits* a number have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know if it fits your defintion of "improvement", but you could do it like this:

```
str.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).GroupBy(x => x).Count();
```

See it here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/t5OW6T

Edit:

As noticed in the comments, you could also use `Distinct` isntead of `GroupBy(x => x)`.

`GroupBy(x => x)` can be useful if you want to know which `digit` occurs how often in the string, this can be done like this:

```
str.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => (x.Key, x.Count()))
```

Where instead of calling `Count` on the "whole" grouping result, you evaluate the `Count` for each individual group of the grouping result.

You may find an example here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/D60ygZ

Comment: Instead of grouping to itself you could also use `Distinct()`. `IsDigit` also considers Unicode digits, i.e. digits of other writing systems. If this isn’t wanted we can use `IsAsciiDigit` since .NET 7.

Comment: @ckuri - absolutly, I was actually in the middle of writing something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eNJIGe - so to evaluate which character occurs how often, but than I remember no wait OP only needs to the total sum, than didn't re-evaluated the code

Answer (score 2):

You can add the digits to HashSet, and then return its size

```
static int Counter(string ID)
{
    var hs = new HashSet<char>();
    foreach (var c in ID) 
        if (char.IsDigit(c)) 
            hs.Add(c);
    return hs.Count;
}
```

Comment: @Fildor The assumption is that the string contains digits only, as he stated "*I have a string of number...*"

Comment: ^^ Which is not wrong. Having been burnt by it, I just adhere to the rule thumb: "Do. Not. Trust. User. Input." :D

Comment: I included your answer in my benchmark and it turns out: doesn't make much of a difference between working on `ReadOnlySpan<char>` or `string` in this case. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that is working on `ReadOnlySapn<char>` for those who prefer that:

```
public static int CountWithHashSetOnReadOnlySpan(ReadOnlySpan<char> input)
{
    HashSet<char> hs = new();
    foreach (var c in input) if (char.IsDigit(c)) hs.Add(c);
    return hs.Count;
}
```

(After his edit, this is now pretty much identical to [Nehorai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218714/982149), just that this works on `ReadOnlySpan<char>` instead of `string`. Usage is the same. I also updated the Benchmark, which shows that **performance is also pretty much identical.**)

I ran this against the accepted code and its `Distinct` variation:

```
|                Method |       Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Gen0 | Allocated |
|---------------------- |-----------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|----------:|
|       GroupByOnString | 1,257.5 ns | 24.83 ns | 23.23 ns | 0.2899 |    2432 B |
|      DistinctOnString |   984.7 ns | 13.76 ns | 12.88 ns | 0.1926 |    1616 B |
|       HashSetOnString |   313.3 ns |  6.25 ns |  6.14 ns | 0.1202 |    1008 B |
| HashSetOnReadOnlySpan |   313.3 ns |  3.20 ns |  2.99 ns | 0.1202 |    1008 B |
```

Mind that this is *nano* seconds. So it's actually not *that* much difference.

The comment

> IsDigit also considers Unicode digits, i.e. digits of other writing systems. If this isn’t wanted we can use IsAsciiDigit since .NET 7.

applies here, too.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vq7ueB).